# Mobile responsive image gallery

Tags: html, css

It's just one of those days and I've got this stuck for some reason. The idea is that the gallery will be given 100% of the width of the page and a row in the gallery will be given 80%. There will be three images will be in each row in columns, each column is 33.3%. I want them to display like in the image below but for some reason two rows just display next to each other.

[Image of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nbGK.png)
My code is as follows:

```css
.gallery-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.gallery-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.gallery-row {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
}

.gallery-row {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.gallery-col {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.gallery-col {
    width: 100%;
}
}

.gallery-img {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-wrap">

<!-- Row 1 Example -->
<div class="gallery-row">

<div class="gallery-col">
<img class="gallery-img " src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Gallery image">
</div>

<div class="gallery-col">
<img class="gallery-img " src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Gallery image">
</div>

<div class="gallery-col">
<img class="gallery-img " src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Gallery image">
</div>
</div>

<!-- Row 2 Example -->
<div class="gallery-row">

<div class="gallery-col">
<img class="gallery-img " src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Gallery image">
</div>

<div class="gallery-col">
<img class="gallery-img " src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Gallery image">
</div>

<div class="gallery-col">
<img class="gallery-img " src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Gallery image">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

On desktop each of the rows should display as a 1x3 grid. On mobile the width of the columns goes to 100% so that the column takes up 80% and there's just one image per row.

I've managed to get lost with this somehow so any help would be appreciated.

`UPDATE`

I've changed

```
.gallery-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

to

```
.gallery-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

which has solved the desktop issue, I just need them to stack properly like in this [Mobile Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEZmU.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: gallery-wrap is set to display:flex. Change it to display: block.

Comment: That's worked for desktop @FaisalRashid. Any idea on how to get them to stack for mobile?

Comment: In the media query for gallery-row, add flex-direction: column.

Comment: Solved it @FaisalRashid, post an answer and I'll accept it for you. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Why are you defining styles in three the same media query. You can just use one. As a side note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting from the comment.

Here's your updated CSS

```
.gallery-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.gallery-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.gallery-row {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}
}

.gallery-row {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.gallery-col {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.gallery-col {
    width: 100%;
}
}

.gallery-img {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. Most helpful solution and nice to deal with thank you so much :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do here is use margin and padding on the gallery object instead of setting it's children to a percentage of the width. You can use display:block to make a row display at 100% width, then increase the padding on the gallery to ensure that everything displays nice. Then, in each row, you can create the image objects that fill out 33.3% of the block container and display:inline.

You can also use media queries to set the padding of the gallery to close to none for mobile devices and set the image objects inside each row to display:block instead of display:inline on media query as well, ensuring they display on top of one another on a mobile sensitive screen.

Though I love that Flexbox is becoming more common and accessible, I don't believe it is needed for things like this.

See this example:

```
`https://codepen.io/cainenielsen/pen/GRKMWzR`
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: I could do that but there's no point and I'd rather wrap them just because it's easier to have the multiple DIVs, especially when I won't be the one editing it most of the time. If you could take a look at the question update I'd be more than appreciative.